# redefinition of default argument for class<template-parameter-1-2>

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, metaprogramming, generic-programming

I'm having some issue with the compiler on this SFINAE. Looks like it doesn't resolve the template before raising this error.
Here is the code:

```
template<typename Sig, typename = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_pointer<Sig>::value>::type>
class   GLFunction { /* class def... */ };

template<typename FP, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<FP>::value>::type>
class   GLFunction { /* class def... */ };
```

Do you know how I can achieve this?

Thx.

Comment: No, because the code tries to define the same template twice, with different definitions. That's not valid. You can't define the same thing twice, especially not in two different ways!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the error, it tells you what's wrong: you can't redefine a default argument, you must only provide it once.

What are you trying to do? Why have you defined the same template twice? Is one of them meant to be a partial specialization?

Why can't you just do it the simple way, like this?

```
// Primary template, with default argument:
template <typename Sig, bool = std::is_pointer<Sig>::value>
class   GLFunction { /* class def... */ };

// Partial specialization used for pointers:
template <typename FP>
class   GLFunction<FP, true> { /* class def... */ };
```

Comment: It's not the same template twice: one is supposed to fail with SFINAE, while the other will pass (look at the not sign). So what i'm trying to do is that at the end there is only one of them.

Comment: You missed the `template` keyword in your example code.

Comment: @skypjack, so did the original that I copied it from.

Comment: @007azzag45, but it **is** the same template twice. A default argument is not part of the template definition, so you have two definitions of the same template. That's not valid. You can't use SFINAE to disable a class template, only to make a specialization not match. You need to define the primary template once, and then write any alternatives as specializations.